# XMPP transport to ICQ

Tags: ruby, xmpp, transport, xmpp4r, icq

I try to send messages to icq via jabber-transport. I tried to use code from this answer 
[XMPP transport to another protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292482/xmpp-transport-to-another-protocol), but I got this message:

```
DEBUG -- : SENDING:
    <message to='12345@icq.jabber.blahblah.ru' xmlns='jabber:client'><body>test
 message from robot</body></message>
=> nil
DEBUG -- : RECEIVED:
    <message from='12345@icq.jabber.blahblah.ru' to='myjit@blahblah.ru/83076
14161416233482839674' type='error'><error code='401' type='auth'><not-authorized
 xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:n
s:xmpp-stanzas'>Error. You must log into the transport before sending messages.<
/text></error><body>test message from robot</body></message>
```

Please explain me: What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmpp4r/client'
include Jabber

Jabber.debug = true
jid = JID::new('myjit@blahblah.ru')
pass = 'pwd'
server = 'jabber.blahblah.ru'
port = '5223'
subj = 'Nagios notification'
user = '12345@icq.jabber.blahblah.ru'
text = 'AAAA AAAA AAAA'
cl = Jabber::Client::new(jid)
cl.use_ssl = true
cl.connect(server,port)
cl.auth(pass) 

#connect to transport
reg=Jabber::Iq.new_register "54321", "pwd2"
reg.to="icq.jabber.blahblah.ru"
cl.send reg

mes = Message::new(user,text)
cl.send(mes)
cl.close()
```

Updated code:

```
cl.connect(server,port)
cl.auth(pass)

# sending initial presence
p = Jabber::Presence.new
cl.send p

mes = Message::new(user,text)
mes.type = :chat

cl.send(mes)
cl.close()
```

returns:

```
D, [2014-11-18T19:01:35.986182 #8084] DEBUG -- : SENDING:
    <presence xmlns='jabber:client'/>
=> nil
irb(main):027:0> D, [2014-11-18T19:01:36.048980 #8084] DEBUG -- : RECEIVED:
    <presence from='icq.jabber.blahblah.ru' to='myjit@blahblah.ru' type='subscri
be'><status/></presence>
```

and still doesnt work

Comment: Transport send you subscription request, you should approve it (`<presence to='myjit@blablah.ru' type='subscribed' />`) and transport will able to see you presence, and, if needed, send presence subscriptions from every icq contact, which you need to approve too. In fact you should do it only first time and can made it with any existing xmpp client.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to register transport only first time, then you need to send [initial presence](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#presence) after session creation.

Comment: Could you write please, how should look like this "initial presence" in my case? (example in XML)